# Jpa merge null attributes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Suppose in JPA I have an entity wih a @OneToMany attribute,
I retrieve it from the db and I set that attribute to null before passing it to the client.

When that entity is submitted again by the client some time later I want to perform a merge,
would that null attribute cause problem, deleting the relation perhaps ?
Should I rebuild the entire Entity before merging ?

Comment: Test it, and you'll see by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it (as per comment above), but I don't see why. If you are talking about the `One` in the many, then either you have a `join table` or there is a foreign key in the `Many` table and simply merging an update shouldn't touch either. If you're talking about the `Many` in the relationship, then if it's a `join table` I don't think it would change it but if it was a foriegn key, i.e., a `ManyToOne` and you set that to null, then yea, you're probably deleting the relationship.